Greenhouse build and electrical
Is there a big cost difference between having electrical set up directly outside the greenhouse vs inside? Foundation has yet to be done.

Doubt it, unless the "inside location" is inside a part of the greenhouse that is actually reliably dry, rather than being a wet area either way (which is my gut reaction to anything inside a typical greenhouse, unless it's separated off into a dry service area by water-proof walls.) In either location you'll do well to think about how many sleeves, of what sizes, and where to put through the foundation so you you don't have to drill the holes later, though. Easier to put a sleeve in the form. Get your UFER ground in there and make darn sure nobody goes and cuts off the part that sticks out.
